# NonParallelPlanReason = MaxDOPSetToOne when maxdop set to 4

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, parallelism

Running SQL Server 2014 on both servers.

While I was attempting to find out why a procedure was running faster on Server B than it was on Server A I found that on Server B the query plan says the Degree of Parallelism = 1 while Server A says Degree of Parallelism = 0 and the NonParallelPlanReason = MaxDopSetToOne.  I'm guessing this is why I'm seeing the difference in my timings for the procedure.  However both servers are set to MaxDop 4 with the same threshold and both plans are returning as almost identical.

I'm at a loss for why one server is choosing parallelism while another is not when the configurations are the same and the code is exactly the same.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Why would a NonParallelPlanReason be given as MaxDopSetToOne when the MaxDop is configured to 4?

I've posted the plans on brentozar's pastetheplan.

- [ServerA plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1Tqoht0z)
- [ServerB plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJcGh2FAG)

Both servers are showing:

```
name                            minimum    maximum  config_value  run_value
cost threshold for parallelism      0       32767       1000         1000
max degree of parallelism           0       32767          4            4
```

- Resource Governor is disabled
- `@@Version` for ServerA = Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU5)
- `@@Version` for ServerB = Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU2-GDR)
- ServerA is not a VM
- ServerB is an Azure VM

Comment: Is one server Express edition? Using resource governor? Bad VM CPU configuration?

Comment: Both are using 2014 Enterprise Edition.  Both are on similar though not exactly the same hardware.

Comment: You're going to have to do some digging or provide the query plans or something. This is way too broad as it stands.

Comment: We'll need more information about the hardware (and if it's a VM, the host as well) to help with this question, as Erik has noted.

Comment: I've uploaded the explain plans  and answered questions as best I can.  I'm trying to find out about the VM CPU Configuration still Erik.

Comment: Could you provide links to the plans?

Comment: I did.  The post was edited afterward to make the ServerA Plan and ServerB Plan links.  If you click on them they should go there.

Comment: just to make it easy...PlanA https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1Tqoht0z
PlanB https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJcGh2FAG